# TS type for Material-UI MenuItem + ForwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to wrap a `menuItem` from material-ui, and wrap it with forwardRef.

Typescript complains that in `forwardRef<MenuItem, Props>` `TS2749: 'MenuItem' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MenuItem'?`

But MenuItem is type annotated and should be working fine. Changing the code to `typeof MenuItem`  doesn't help as then TS complains at the place where I am assigning the ref on MenuItem:

> TS2769: No overload matches this call
>
> [...] Type 'HTMLLIElement' provides no match for the signature '<C extends ElementType>(props: { component: C; } & { button: false; } & { alignItems?: "center" | "flex-start" | undefined; autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; button?: boolean | undefined; ... 7 more ...; selected?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Omit<...>): Element'.

So what should be the type in `forwardRef` then?

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem'


type Props = {...}

export const InputSelectOption = forwardRef<MenuItem, Props>(
  function InputSelectOption (props: Props, ref): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <MenuItem {...props} ref={ref}>
        [...]
      </MenuItem>
    )
  })
```

Comment: `forwardRef<MenuItem, Props>` Here MenuItem is actually the component and not a type or interface. So Typescript is  asking you to change it to `forwardRef<typeof MenuItem, Props>`. This change will actually bring out the _type of_ the MenuItem and bind it with forwardRef

Comment: @boop_the_snoot thanks, I tried that, but as I wrote in the description, then it complaints that I cannot assign this ref to MenuItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type to use is `HTMLLIElement`.

From the source: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.3/packages/material-ui/src/MenuItem/MenuItem.js#L52-L53

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGjjWgHcMolS0BfWqCEOAcijKVeAbgCwAKFCRYiALIoAdlgCSMFCA5ouPXgAEQGNVGAYcAWizAA9OWgoREiTACeYFHAAKXMEQC8iOAB9AH4ALjgFFAA3FCg4NjFxCRQAD2l4WwUCeGUFMCwYAGUUHBRKAHkwGGAIBTh-OihGZlYAHgAJABVZABke5QBRUpBFak9vAgA+AAppsAmaATQASnrJuGmJODhW+SVVdUQAOhP5iB8OJd8EJbZJhCsAKjgTo7hHqzZWqz2VNRBJhJlstEkA)

```ts
import {default as React, forwardRef} from 'react';
import {MenuItem} from '@material-ui/core';

type Props = { _?: never };

export const InputSelectOption = forwardRef<HTMLLIElement, Props>((props, ref) => (
  <MenuItem {...props} ref={ref}>{/* ... */}</MenuItem>
));
```

---

If you are unsure about how to type an attribute, you can use IntelliSense to discover it by hovering over the attribute before filling its value:

[image]